# Is it sin to sleep with a prostitute before marriage being a shudra?

Tags: rituals, kamadeva

Being a shudra, I'm eager to know whether sleeping with a prostitute is considered as a sinful act in hinduism.

Comment: It's not just Shudra, it applies to every varna. @Ravi

Comment: See this answer too. It is relevant: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15684/what-place-does-a-thing-like-prostitution-occupy-in-the-hindu-context/16174#16174

Comment: You can check this out https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58183/24460