# Scriptures and Adultery

Tags: scripture, vedas, smriti, itihasa, adultery

What do Hindu Scriptures remark about adultery for wives and for husbands? Are there specific exemptions or also the references that injunct punishment of any kind for adulterous wives or adulterous husbands? What do the Vedas and Other texts (Smritis, Puranas, itihasas, et al) say about this?

Thank You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarification regarding adultery, extra-marital relations](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8728/clarification-regarding-adultery-extra-marital-relations)