Dharma for homosexuals
I am 21 years old male, currently in college. I have been interested in dharma, bhakti and knowledge of śāstra from childhood. But, on attaining puberty, I realised I am attracted to men and eventually found out what scriptures have to say about homosexuals. And I was very sad and depressed and prayed to Bhagavān as to why I am homosexual though I know it's due to karma. Previously I used to hate myself and was determined to be a lifelong celibate, only to realise in last three years celibacy isn't for everyone, especially not for homosexuals, as you have to live in an ashram with people you are attracted to. Slowly, over the years, I have accepted myself, I mean what choice did I have, you can't live your whole life hating yourself. Now, I want intimacy, relationship. But, for homosexuals there is no provision in Shastra for sexual activities within the regulation of dharma, like there is for straight people through vivaha and garbhadhana samskara.It's just mentioned as sinful with no details on what they are going to do. Not just sexual activity, I also want to know what is my dharma. I am super stressed out and can't focus on anything in my life as I think of future— on one hand I want relationship but am guilty of sins and on the other hand I am confused that how I am going to live my life. If I become like every other gay guy, then I will incur sins and this human life will be wasted which should have been used attaining moksha, and if I don't then I am afraid I will be alone and regret this in my old age. I feel sad and pity myself seeing straight guys being happy. I am dead from inside. I don't want to violate dharma, but the desires are strong and with strong desires I can't focus on bhakti sadhana as well. I feel agitated even in the midst of young make bhaktas in temples. Please help me someone with shastric guidance. Also, I want proper shastra based answer from traditional understanding and don't want new 20th/21st century interpretations like Smritis are not Vedic, hinduism support homosexuality blah blah blah. Please help!

This question is similar to: Vedas and Vedic dharma on homosexuality. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8728/clarification-regarding-adultery-extra-marital-relations/8734#8734

There is no text in Hinduism that explicitly or implicitly condemns homosexuality. See my answer here about texts that are produced as proof of condemnation of homosexuality in Hindu scriptures.
Having said that, there are no texts in Hinduism that condones homosexuality as well and there is no text that can ratify homosexual unions. The only Dharma you can pursue in your situation is a scholastic one. You should spend your time studying scriptures if possible in the original Sanskrit language. This will help you get more clarity as well as you learn more.

Hinduism has no official view on homosexuality.
There is a Manu Smriti verse that might be talking about homosexuality.

Beating Brahmins, smelling things like alcohol that should not be
smelled, crookedness and having sex with a man leads to loss of
caste.

Manu Smriti 11.67
This verse if directed to a man would be about homosexuality. It can be argued, however, that Hinduism does not condemn homosexuals. The argument goes as follows: The four purusharthas (goals of life) according to Hindu dharma are artha (worldly wealth), kama (desire including sexual desire), dharma, and moksha. Thus Hindu Dharma accepts the legitimacy of sexual desire and this must include homosexual desire. It doesn't matter whether you are transsexual, heterosexual or homosexual if you want to remain in the endless birth-death-birth cycle of Samsara. All these are simply different varieties of lust. You have to give up all varieties of lust if you want to escape from the cycle of Samsara i.e. attain Moksha. Both heterosexual and homosexual desire must be abandoned to attain moksha.

Dharma, understood as the Supreme Good of man, can never have wealth
as its reward. Nor has wealth, understood as an aid to the achievement
of Dharma, been conceived as an aid for the attainment of kama (sexual
desire). Kama in its turn is not a call to indulgence in sexual
pleasures, but a mere inducement implanted by the Creator to make life
unbroken. And as for life, it has the quest of the Supreme Truth as
its end – not certainly Karma (i.e. performance of rituals and social
duties) for the attainment of wealth (prosperity here and heaven
hereafter).

Srimad Bhagavata Purana I.2.9-10
It just accepts homosexuality as a fact.

When the Jiva, who is by nature self-luminous, forgets the Bhagavan,
the supreme Teacher and the Soul of all souls, and become identified
with the Gunas of Prakriti, then that Jiva, strengthening this
identification and attachment through the senses and their objects,
engages himself in various actions, and bears the ultimate fruits of
these actions by way of embodiments in wombs that are high or low.
Sometimes, on the strength of actions of a Sattvika nature, the Jiva
attains to worlds of light; sometimes by Rajasika actions, to the
world of men full of sorrows and difficulties; and sometimes by
Tamasika actions to low worlds of darkness and suffering. The Jiva
who is blinded by ignorance, sometimes is embodied as a man, sometimes
as a woman, sometimes as a neuter.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana IV.29.26–29
Hindu scripture lumps all people who are not masculine or feminine as neuter. I am assuming that neuter stands for LGBTQ people. The above passage suggests that both straight people and LGBTQ people are blinded by ignorance. All lust must be abandoned if these people want to attain moksha.
Nowadays some Hindu priests are officiating over LGBTQ marriages.
https://www.womensweb.in/2021/11/meet-the-hindu-priest-officiating-lgbtq-weddings-in-the-indian-diaspora-raja-gopal-bhattar-nov21wk4sc/#:~:text=November%2026%2C%202021-,Meet%20The%20Hindu%20Priest%20Officiating%20LGBTQ%20Weddings%20In%20The%20Indian,lineage%20of%20Hindu%20scholars%20%26%20pundits!
Read the above post and see what this priest has to say about such marriages. Many Hindu priests are officiating such marriages in India.

You have again got yourself in hot waters. 1) The Manusmrti verse you stated doesn't necessarily refers to homosexuality exclusively. It can also mean pederastry & war-time rape of men. For example eyewitness accounts of the fall of Constantinople in 1453 described Sultan Mehmed VI raping the Byzantine queen as well as boys of the Byzantine aristocrats. 2) Marriage is a holy sacrament in Hinduism, not a religious supplement to a civil union as in white societies. To conduct a religious ceremony for something which leads to nowhere in the afterlife is absolutely anathema in Hinduism.

Why should I be in hot water? I never claimed that the MS verse exclusively applied to homosexuality. It is a possibility. I don't understand why you are bringing in the afterlife issue here? Did I make the claim that the Hindu priest officiating on the marriage of two homosexuals has anything to do with afterlife? I only pointed out that homosexual weddings among Hindus attended by priests are now occurring in India and outside. This is just a fact. Are you questioning the fact?

Rupa Goswami says in the Bhaktirasamrtasindhu that all scriptural injunctions are created with the sole aim of fostering the soul towards liberation. Marriage has been formulated with the aims of 1) legitimate fulfillment of sexual urges without harming the society, 2) procreation of pious offspring who will become torchbearers of the religion & release the forefathers from the pitr-rna. Homosexuality leads to nowhere in the afterlife, for it neither gives fulfillment to sexual desires (on the contray it increases it) nor does it create progeny who can liberate from pitr-rna.

But in this Kaliyuga, it is normal for the people to disregard for their afterlife, which is inreversible & has been divinely ordained, so nothing can be done in this regard. While there is no problem with a non-religious civil union, but conducting religious rituals for an event not designed for that purpose is nothing but wilful blasphemy, Its like asking to conduct a yajna on occasion of Christmas or making tribal priests officiate in worship of canonical deities.

Our religion never had so much controversy over LGBTQ issues. And in the vast ocean of Sanskrit literature, there is hardly any reference to it. The only recorded gay man in Indian history is one Hindu-origin enslaved lover of Qutubuddin Khalji. And let's be honest - all these controversy over the status of homosexuality in our religion boils down to only this fact - that the whites have started to make homosexuality mainstream, so we must also do the same in order to gain approval of the whites. I don't understand what obsession people have with white validitation.

And before any name-calling begins, I would like to clarify that neither do I believe homosexuality leads to eternal damnation (that's a completely Abrahamic concept) nor that homosexual people must be shunned completely (another Abrahamic concept). A homosexual man is no better than a whore-adfict, for neither of them direct towards moksha.

The priest is performing this ritual, but he cannot defend this practice because the scriptures categorically say homosexuality is a sin. Even the Grihyasutras where the wedding ritual is described clearly says the marriage is between a man and a woman. So whatever this fellow is doing is against Hindu sastras. He created his own ritual; this is not a Hindu ritual as it is against Hindu sastras. Just because some self-proclaimed priest performs some ritual that does not make it a Hindu ritual. So I think this link you shared is pointless.

The neuter gender is not lgbtq. Neuter is only transgender. So your quote from Bhagavata is irrelevant here. Transgenders are accepted in Hindu society, but not homosexuals. Homosexuals are condemned clearly. So, it is not true that there is no official view of Hinduism on Homosexuals.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay I don't think transgender is accepted. Neuter means someone who cannot reproduce like Arjuna became Bruhannala and there is another one in Dhevi Bhagavatham that I cannot recall of.
