# What was the surname of Lord Krishna?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana

I want to know the surname of Lord Krishna. Is there any reference from scriptures which points to Krishna's surname?

Comment: I don't think 'surnames' existed then. Even so he was known as Vasudeva Krishna.

Comment: Perhaps ,  it is yadav

Comment: Varma since he was born kshatriya. Or he could have taken on Nanda's surname who was a vaisya. So Nanda's caste-title could be sreshti.

Comment: @Surya There were surnames; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5271/36 You can see lots of surnames in the Rig Veda Anukramani in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36p

Comment: @Keshav Those can be surnames, although they are more like, Mr X, the son of Mr Y.

Comment: @Surya Well, they're patronymics that would be passed down in a very specific manner.  Like there's a reason why the sons of Dhritarashtra are called Kauravas after Kuru, but the sons of Pandu are called Pandavas after Pandu.

Comment: Vrishni Yadav Chandravanshi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrishni

Comment: If you have seen movie "Oh My God" then you must have heard name of Actor Akshay Kumar as `Krishna vasudev Yadav` who apparently was playing character of krishna. (Just for reference)

Comment: @moonstar2001 He cannot be a Shreshti as he ruled Yadava Kingdom from Dwaraka. So it locks down to Varma.

Comment: @Yogi Who ruled Yadava kingdom? Neither Krishna nor Nanda did. Nanda was a vassal/village headman types. Krishna did not rule any kingdom in honor of the curse incurred by Yadu, his vamsa's moola purusha.

Comment: @moonstar2001 What curse? but still he fought like a true Kshatriya had many wives etc.

Comment: @Yogi the curse was that the descendants cannot rule over a kingdom.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Then who ruled Dwaraka?

Comment: @Yogi Dwaraka was a separate city built specially for Krishna and his followers who fled the Yadava kingdom of Mathura. Ugrasena ruled yadava kingdom after kamsa. Dwaraka is not mentioned as a kingdom but rather as a capital city of Anarta. Krishna was born a kshatriya and conducted himself as a kshatriya. He may not have taken Nanda's last name but honoring parents that fostered him is not a far-fetched concept.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Varma is not a surname. It is added after upanayana. It should be yadava. Because the progenitor of the dynasty is yadu.