# Last name of Shree Ram and Shree Krishna?

Tags: gods, caste-system, name

I always wondered what were the last name of avatars - Shree Ram and Shree Krishna. I know that Ram was kshatriya and Krishan was nand. But I don't know their real last name. Did they even had one? Or did they just used their father's name as their last name?

Comment: "Krishan was nand" -what does that mean?...Krishna was also Kshatriya.....bdw their dynasty name was their last name... Raghav/Kukusthi for Rama...Yadav/Madhav/Vrishni for Krishna...

Comment: Shree Krishna was a Yadav and Lord Ram was a Suryawanshi. But I am not sure if they used last names or not

Comment: Partial duplicate of [What was the surname of Lord Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9599/5212).