# Name all the hundred Kauravas in Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, kauravas

Name all the one hundred Kauravas (Dhritarashtra's sons) who were born in pots.

Comment: [Should I search on Internet before asking question?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/224/467)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01118.htm) of the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata, Vaishampayana tells Arjuna's great-grandson Janamejaya all 101 sons of Dhritarashtra:

> Their names, O king, according to the order of birth, are Duryodhana, **Yuyutsu**, Duhsasana, Duhsaha, **Duhsala**, Jalasandha, Sama, Saha, Vinda and Anuvinda, Durdharsha, Suvahu, Dushpradharshana, Durmarshana and Durmukha, Dushkarna, and Karna; Vivinsati and Vikarna, Sala, Satwa, Sulochana, Chitra and Upachitra, Chitraksha, Charuchitra, Sarasana, Durmada and Durvigaha, Vivitsu, Vikatanana; Urnanabha and Sunabha, then Nandaka and Upanandaka; Chitravana, Chitravarman, Suvarman, Durvimochana; Ayovahu, Mahavahu, Chitranga, Chitrakundala, Bhimavega, Bhimavala, Balaki, Balavardhana, Ugrayudha; Bhima, Karna, Kanakaya, Dridhayudha, Dridhavarman, Dridhakshatra, Somakitri, Anudara; Dridhasandha, Jarasandha, Satyasandha, Sada, Suvak, Ugrasravas, Ugrasena, Senani, Dushparajaya, Aparajita, Kundasayin, Visalaksha, Duradhara; Dridhahasta, Suhasta, Vatavega, and Suvarchas; Adityaketu, Vahvashin, Nagadatta, Agrayayin; Kavachin, Krathana, Kunda, Kundadhara, Dhanurdhara; the heroes, Ugra and Bhimaratha, Viravahu, Alolupa; Abhaya, and Raudrakarman, and Dridharatha; Anadhrishya, Kundabhedin, Viravi, Dhirghalochana Pramatha, and Pramathi and the powerful Dhirgharoma; Dirghavahu, Mahavahu, Vyudhoru, Kanakadhvaja; Kundasi and Virajas.

And yes, I said *101* sons, not 100, because in addition to the hundred Kauravas, Dhritarashtra had one additional son, Yuyutsu, with a Vaishya woman.  As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3282/36) about the birth of the Kauravas, Gandhari was pregnant with the Kauravas for two years. Dhritarashtra was worried that Gandhari would never give birth, so as a precaution he decided to have a son with a Vaishya woman, as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01116.htm) of the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata.  In any case, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6609/36), Yuyutsu was a virtuous individual who decided to switch to the Pandava side in the Mahabharata war, and he served as a regent when the Pandavas left their kingdom to Arjuna's grandson Parikshit.

And in addition to his 101 sons, Dhritarashtra also had a daughter named Duhsala.  She was born the same way as the 100 Kauravas, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3282/36). And she married Jayadratha, a king who fought on the Kaurava side, infamous for blocking the Pandavas from rescuing Arjuna's son Abhimanyu during the Mahabharata war.

Comment: Interesting that 4 of the sons where namesake of "Bhima*" (& "Jarasandha", "Karna" too), including 1 named literally as "Bhima" itself! However such names are not present in @Kedarnath's answer. However I really find strange that, 1 son was named as "Ugrayudha", the [same name king](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyavati#Birth_of_children_and_grandchildren) actually lusted after Dhritarashtra's grandmother Satyavati and enraged Bhishma by asking Satyavati for marriage immediately after Shantanu's death.

Comment: @iammilind Actually they are present in Kedarnath's answer, it's just that Wikipedia spells things differently; it says Bheema rather than Bhima, Jaraasandha rather than Jarasandha, etc.  In any case, a lot of these names are fairly common Kshatriya names; I know plenty of Vedic kings named Bhima, like Bhima of Vidarbha.  And names starting with Ugra, or Chitra, or Satya, and ending with Yudha, or Jaya, or Dhara, or Sena was extremely common for Kshatriyas.  So I don't think the fact that someone was named Ugrayudha is any more than a coincidence, like an American naming someone Steve.

Comment: @Iammilind By the way, the reason I know about Bhima of Vidarbha is that he's one of the kings mentioned in the Aitareya Brahmana of the Rig Veda: see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8007/36

Comment: While fixing a couple of typos, I also noticed that, preceding the BQ, you said 101 _sons_ but the BQ also includes Duhsala (the _daughter_). Interesting that Yuyutsu is born after Duryodhana but before Duhsasana which means the Vaishya woman also got pregnant simultaneously as Gandhari or an year after because Gandhari remained pregnant for 2 years but then she waited to deliver Yuyutsu until after Duryodhana is born.

Comment: @sv. If you count, you'll find that the block quote contains 102 names, because it includes both Yuyutsu and Duhsala.  And yeah, Yuyutsu's mother got pregnant sometime during Gandhari's pregnancy, presumably within the last nine or ten months of Gandhari's pregnancy.  It is interesting that Yuyutsu is mentioned as being born between Duryodhana and Dushasana, because my understanding is that the 100 Kauravas were born more or less simultaneously.

Comment: Something's not right, maybe a translation error. At [this link](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01118.htm) too, Janamejaya only asks for Dhritarashtra's _**sons**_, but Vaisampayana includes *Duhsala*, the _**daughter**_ too, in the list. The Sanskrit word could mean _**children**_ (instead of _**sons**_), then Vaisampayana's answer would have made sense. (Hope you got what I'm try to get at.)

Comment: @sv. Here's the Sanskrit verse: "jyeṣṭhānujyeṣṭhatāṃ teṣāṃ nāmadheyāni cābhibho | dhṛtarāṣṭrasya putrāṇām ānupūrvyeṇa kīrtaya ||" http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01108.htm Putranam means sons, I'm not sure if it can also denote children in general.  By the way, I just noticed that after the listing of 102 names Vaishampayana says in addition there is also Duhsala, so that's another oddity.

Answer (score 7):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaurava),

1. Duryodhana
2. Yuyutsu(half-brother, Dhritirashtra and Vysya servant's son)
3. Dushasana
4. Vikarna
5. Vivinsati
6. Durmukha
7. Duhsalan
8. Jalagandha
9. Sama
10. Saha
11. Vindha
12. Anuvindha
13. Chitrasena
14. Durdarsha
15. Durmarsha
16. Dussaha
17. Durmada
18. Dushkarna
19. Durdhara
20. Durmarshana
21. Durvishaha
22. Durvimochana
23. Dushpradharsha
24. Durjaya
25. Dushparajaya
26. Jaitra
27. Bhurivala
28. Ravi
29. Jayatsena
30. Sujata
31. Srutavan
32. Srutanta
33. Jaya
34. Chitra
35. Upachitra
36. Charuchitra
37. Chitraksha
38. Sarasana
39. Chitrayudha
40. Chitravarman
41. Suvarma
42. Sudarsana
43. Dhanurgraha
44. Vivitsu
45. Subaahu
46. Nanda
47. Upananda
48. Kratha
49. Vatavega
50. Nishagin
51. Kavashin
52. Paasi
53. Vikata
54. Soma
55. Suvarchasas
56. Dhanurdhara
57. Ayobaahu
58. Mahabaahu
59. Chithraamga
60. Chithrakundala
61. Bheemaratha
62. Bheemavega
63. Bheemabela
64. Ugraayudha
65. Kundhaadhara
66. Vrindaaraka
67. Dridhavarma
68. Dridhakshathra
69. Dridhasandha
70. Jaraasandha
71. Sathyasandha
72. Sadaasuvaak
73. Ugrasravas
74. Ugrasena
75. Senaany
76. Aparaajitha
77. Kundhasaai
78. Dridhahastha
79. Suhastha
80. Suvarcha
81. Aadithyakethu
82. Ugrasaai
83. Kavachy
84. Kradhana
85. Kundhy
86. Bheemavikra
87. Alolupa
88. Abhaya
89. Dhridhakarmaavu
90. Dhridharathaasraya
91. Anaadhrushya
92. Kundhabhedy
93. Viraavy
94. Pradhama
95. Amapramaadhy
96. Deerkharoma
97. Suveeryavaan
98. Dheerkhabaahu
99. Kaanchanadhwaja
100. Kundhaasy
101. Virajass
102. Dussala(Daughter)

Answer (score 0):

1.Duryodhana,
2.Dussaasana,
3.Dussaha,
4.Dussala,
5.Jalasandha,
6.Sama,
7.Saha,
8.Vinda,
9.Anuvinda,
10.Durdarsha,
11.Subaahu,
12.Dushpradarshana,
13.Durmarshana,
14.Durmukha,
15.Dushkarna,
16.Karna,
17.Vivimsata,
18.Vikarna,
19.Sala,
20.Satva,
21SulOchana,
22.Chitra,
23.Upachitra
24.Chitraaksha,
25.Charucitra,
26.Saraasana,
27.Durmada,
28.Durvigaaha,
29.Vivitsa,
30.VikaTaanana,
31.Nornanaabha,
32.Sunaabha,
33.Nanda,
34.Upananda,
35.Chitrabaana,
36.Chitravarma,
37.Suvarma,
38.DurvimOcana,
39.AyObaaha,
40.Mahaabaaha
41.Chitranga,
42.Chitrakundala,
43.Bheemavega,
44.Bheemabalaa,
45.Balaaka,
46.Balavardha,
47.NOgraayudha,
48.SushEna,
49.Kundadhaara,
50.MahOdara,
51.Chitraayudha,
52.Nishanga,
53.Paasa,
54.Brundaaraka,
55.Dhrudhavarma,
56.Dhrudhakshatra,
57.Somakeerthi,
58.Anoodara,
59.Dhrudhasandha,
60.Jaraasandha,
61. Sada,
62.Suvaaga,
63.Ugrasrava,
64.Ugrasena,
65.Senaani,
66.Dushpraaja,
67.Aparaajitha,
68.Kundasaayi,
69.Visaalaksha,
70.Duraadhara,
71.Durjaya,
72.Dhrudhahasta,
73.Suhastha,
74.VaatavEga,
75.Suvarcha,
76.Aaadityaketa,
77.Bahvaasi,
78.Naagadatta,
79.Agrayaayi,
80.Kavacha,
81.Kradhana,
82.Kundina,
83.DhanurdharOgra,
84.Bheemaradha,
85.Veerabaahu,
86.ValOla,
87.Rudrakarma,
88.Dhrudaradhaasrya,
89.Adrushya,
90.KundabhEdi,
91.Viravi,
92.Pramadha,
93.Pramaadhi,
94.DeergharOma,
95.Dheerghabaahu,
96.OoDhOra,
97.Kanakadhvaja,
98.Upaabhaya,
99.Kundaasi
100.Vijarasa.
101.Dusala-Sister of Duryodhana
102.Yuyutsu- Step brother of Duryodhana born from dassi.

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01118.htm