# Bhisma defeating Parashuram

Tags: mahabharata

In Mahabharata, there is a mention of Bhisma defeating Parashuram in a battle that ensued over Bhisma not accepting Amba as his wife even after requested by Parashuram himself. This seems to be ridiculous as Parashuram is an incarnation of Vishnu, while, Bhisma was more or less a human being. So, how can a human being become more powerful than a Godly incarnation?

Comment: Parashurama wasn't defeated in battle, he voluntarily put his weapons down at the request of his ancestors, because Bhishma was destined to be killed by Arjuna; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2178/36

Comment: @Keshav: But, I have read that during the fight, Bhisma invoked a weapon, to which Parashuram was not capable of countering. Then, divine voice asked both the fighters to stop.

Comment: No, that Mahabharata chapter doesn't say Parashurama was incapable of countering it.

Comment: @Keshav: I the Mahabharata serial, it was shown that Parashurama was actually incapable of countering that weapon.

Comment: I think that's just artistic license on the creator's part; the Mahabharata chapters I quoted in my answer don't say Parashurama was incapable of countering the Prashwapastra.  TV serials are known for taking license in the story.

Comment: @Keshav: Not only in the TV serial, I have read about Parashuram's incapability in many online sources too. So, there has to be some thuth on it.

Comment: Well, it's not in the Mahabharata, so I don't think there's any truth to it.  The Mahabharata makes clear that Parashurama is asked to stop not because there's a threat on his life from the Prashwapastra, but rather because if he were to continue fighting he would kill Bhishma, and Bhishma is supposed to die at the hands of Arjuna.