# Lineage of Pandavas?

Tags: mahabharata, history, pandavas

I found the following compilation of the genealogy of the Pandavas, but I am unable to verify its authenticity or find its sources. In known literature there seems to be no knowledge of the descendants of Ashwamedhadatta, the son of Janamajeya and later kings.

http://www.hindunet.org/hindu_history/medieval/kings_chron.html

Are there any historical records that mention the kings that come after Ashwamedhadatta?

Answer (score 10):

The descendants of the Pandavas are listed by the sage Parashara in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp114.htm) of the Vishnu Purana, starting with Arjuna's grandson Parikshit:

> I WILL now enumerate the kings who, will reign in future periods The present monarch, Paríkshit, will have four sons, Janamejaya, Śrutasena, Ugrasena, and Bhímasena. The son of Janamejaya will be Śatáníka, who will study the Vedas under Yájnyawalkya, and military science with Kripa; but becoming dissatisfied with sensual enjoyments, he will acquire spiritual knowledge from the instructions of Śaunaka, and ultimately obtain salvation. His son will be Aswamedhadatta (a son given by the gods in reward for the sacrifice of a horse); his son will be Asíma-krishńa; his son will be Nichakra, who will remove the capital to Kauśámbí, in consequence of Hastinápura being washed away by the Ganges; his son will be Ushńa; his son will be Chitraratha; his son will be Vrishńimat; his son will be Susheńa; his son will be Sunítha; his son will be Richa; his son will be Nrichakshu; his son will be Sukhíhala; his son will be Pariplava; his son will be Sunaya; his son will be Medhávin; his son will be Nripanjaya; his son will be Mridu; his son will be Tigma; his son will be Vrihadratha; his son will be Vasudána; and his son will be another Śatáníka; his son will be Udayana; his son will be Ahínara; his son will be Khańd́apáni; his son will be Niramitra; his son will be Kshemaka: of him this verse is recited; "The race which gave origin to Brahmans and Kshatriyas, and which was purified by regal sages, terminated with Kshemaka; in the Kali age."

Arjuna's descendant Kshemaka was killed by his minister, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7506/36).  Thus ended the glorious Kuru dynasty.

Comment: This a prediction of lineage. Is there any historical record(aposteriori) on at-least one of the above mentioned kings who come after Janamajeya's son.

Comment: @Naveen Yeah, the Vayu Purana was recited by Ugrashrava (aka Suta) during a Yagna conducted during the reign of Janamajeya's great-grandson Asimakrishna, as described in this excerpt from the Vayu Purana: http://gdurl.com/u-GX

Comment: So after 25 generations kuruvansha will end with kshemaka but why I mean how did it came to an abrupt end?

Comment: @Yogi Like I said, Kshemaka was killed by his minister, who became king and started a new dynasty.  Ministers killing their king and taking over the kingdom was unfortunately a common thing in ancient India (at least in the Kali Yuga).

Comment: Minister Must be a bramhin how can he be so filthy??

Comment: @Yogi Ministers aren't always Brahmins.  I think Kshemaka's minister Vishrava was a Kshatriya, because otherwise I don't see how he and his descendants would have been accepted as king.  As far how he could be so filthy, it is the Kali Yuga after all, so there's lots of evil going on.

Comment: the minister might also be converted to kshatriya because he had all the rule under his hands and btw can any body like bramhin be converted to lower casts like kshatriya??

Comment: No, Brahmanas can't be converted to other castes, at least not in their current birth.  So I think it was just a Kshatriya advisor.

Comment: Who is **I** in **I WILL now**? (for clarity, can you update the answer?)

Comment: OK, I edited my answer.  The person speaking is Vyasa's father Parashara, who is telling the Vishnu Purana to the sage Maitreya.  Parashara is the author of either two or three of the Puranas depending on how you count.  He composed the Vishnu Purana and he composed another work called the Shiva Purana, but Vyasa split up Parashara's Shiva Purana into the two texts we now call the Shiva Purana and the Vayu Purana.  Vyasa is the author of the other 16 Puranas, though.

Comment: @sv. By the way, your comment led me to look more into Parashara and Maitreya, so I just posted a question related to them: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9308/36

Comment: Kshemaka stopped become a king in 1634 BC?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I heard first ruler of Nanda dynasty killed Kshemaka??