# Do we have any record of events in any previous Kaliyuga?

Tags: puranas, yuga, time, vyasa, kali-yuga

We know that at the end of every Dwapara yuga, Vyasa compiles the events of the yugas into various puranas. These puranas sometimes contains stories and other details about Kritayuga, Dwapara Yuga and Treta Yuga of different Mahayugas also. But I wonder why I have not come across any stories from any previous Kaliyuga. At the most, what we read about is the stories around starting of Kaliyuga like those related to Parikshit or Janamejaya, etc but not later part of Kaliyuga. Do we know why is it so? Is it that there are no incarnations in later part of any previous Kaliyuga, therefore there were no stories, or are there any stories which I am unaware of?

Comment: Vishnu's incarnation Indrapramati killed all the evil people in one of the Kali Yugas of the Swayambhuva Manvantara.  And Vishnu's incarnation Parashurama killed the kings of the Earth during the 19th Kali Yuga of the present Vaivasvata Manvantara.  And Vishnu's incarnation Matsya saved king Satyavrata, the previous birth of Vaivasvata Manu, during the last Kali Yuga of the Chakshusha Manvantara.

Comment: The reason why our scriptures only discuss the beginning of the present Kali Yuga is that that's when the Puranas were composed.  So any description of events after that are only in the form of prophecies.  In fact, I think the chronologically latest event described (in the past tense) in Hindu scripture is a Yagna conducted during the reign of Janamejaya's great-grandson Asimakrishna; see the Vayu Puranas excerpt linked in the comments section of my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7749/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks for your reply but can you please put that as an answer explaining the stories or giving links.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are multiple incarnations of Vishnu which took place during previous Kali Yugas:

1. **Pramati**: Just as Vishnu'e incarnation Kalki will come at the end of the present Kali Yuga and kill all the evil people, during one of the Kali Yugas of the Swayambhuva Manvantara Vishnu incarnated as a king named Pramati and killed all the evil people, as described in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/KrG5) from the Matsya Purana:

> King Pramati of the Bhrigu family and Chandramasa gotra was born at the end of Swayambhuva Manu in the Sandhyamsha period, to inflict proper punishment on the sinners.  That king travelled all over the earth for 30 years and collected arms and ammunitions, elephants,
> horses and chariots and marched with a vast army consisting of horses
> and elephants and accompanied by 100,000 Brahmana soldiers armed
> with various kinds of weapons, against the Mlecchas and destroyed
> them. After killing all the Sudra kings he annihilated all the hypocrites
> After destroying all the sinners and subduing the people living in
> the North, central regions, the mountaineers, the inhabitants in the East
> and West, the residents on the Vindhyas, the Deccanis, the Dravidians,
> the Singhalese, the inhabitants of the Mleccha countnes...

> King Pramati was born of Vishnu's part in Manu's family and was famous as Chandramasa.  He roamed about the Earth for 20 years and killed all the wicked men in his 32nd year.

2. **Parashurama**: Vishnu's incarnation Parashurama killed the kings of the earth 21 times, thereby bringing about the end of the Kali Yuga and beginning of the Satya Yuga, as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07067.htm) of the Drona Parva of the Mahabharata:

> Even the great ascetic Rama, the hero worshipped by all heroes, that son of Jamadagni, of great fame, will die, without being contented (with the period of his life). **Rooting out all evils from the earth, he caused the primeval Yuga to set in.** Having obtained unrivalled prosperity, no fault could be seen in him. His father having been slain and his calf having been stolen by the Kshatriyas, he without any boast, slew Kartavirya who had never been vanquished before by foes. With his bow he slew four and sixty times ten thousand Kshatriyas already within the jaws of death. In that slaughter were included fourteen thousand Brahmana-hating Kshatriyas of the Dantakura country, all of whom he slew. Of the Haihayas, he slew a thousand with his short club, a thousand with his sword, and a thousand by hanging. Heroic warriors, with their cars, steeds, and elephants, lay dead on the field, slain by the wise son of Jamadagni, enraged at the slaughter of his father. And Rama, on that occasion, slew ten thousand Kshatriyas with his axe.

By the way, see my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/433/36) for what happened after Parashurama killed all those kings.

3. **Matsya**: In the last Kali Yuga of the Chakshusha Manvantara, Vishnu's incarnation Matsya the fish rescued the king Satyavrata, also known as Vaivasvata Manu, from a flood that comes at the end of every Manavantara, as described in [this chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/24/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam:

> When King Satyavrata spoke in this way, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who at the end of the yuga had assumed the form of a fish to benefit His devotee and enjoy His pastimes in the water of inundation, responded as follows. The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: "O King, who can subdue your enemies, on the seventh day from today the three worlds — Bhūḥ, Bhuvaḥ and Svaḥ — will all merge into the water of inundation.  When all the three worlds merge into the water, a large boat sent by Me will appear before you."

Expect this, this chapter of [Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423657.html) mentiones about King Ama, who lived at one of previous Dwapara-Kali yuga transtition.

> 12-13. Now, when the **advent of Kali Age was imminent, at the end of Dvāpara**, when Kali had not yet started, there was a king named Āma who became the ruler of Kānyakubja. He was glorious, a knower of Dharma, calm, self-controlled, eager to maintain justice, of good conduct and devoted to truth and piety, O excellent king.

To answer your other question, the reason why our scriptures only discuss the beginning of the present Kali Yuga is that that's when the Puranas were composed. So any description of events after that are only in the form of prophecies, for instance the Vishnu Purana's prophecy of the Janamajeaya's descendants discussed in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7749/36).

As far as I know, the chronologically latest event described (in the past tense) in Hindu scripture, excluding Tamil scripture like the Alwars' poems, is a Yagna conducted during the reign of Janamejaya's great-grandson Adisimakrishna, which is described in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/u-GX) from the Vayu Purana.  In fact, it is during this Yagna that the Vayu Purana was recited by Ugrashrava (aka Suta).

Comment: I thought parashurama is born in 19th treta yuga. So  is that the reference about 19th kaliyuga?

Comment: @sysinit Yeah, Parashurama was born in the 19th Treta Yuga, so I assume the Kali Yuga being referred to is the Kali Yuga of that Mahayuga.  Parashurama is still alive to this day, so in principle it could have happened in any Kali Yuga between the 19th Treta Yuga and the 24th Treta Yuga (when Rama lived), but I don't think Parashurama lived through any Kali Yuga-Satya Yuga transitions before the one that he was responsible for.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks a lot, although a knew a bit about these stories but didn't new that these happened during previous Kaliyugas.

Comment: Is it clearly mentioned that the slaying of Kartavirya Arjuna happened during a Kali Yuga?

Comment: @Naveen Yes, it says "Rooting out all evils from the earth, he caused the primeval Yuga to set in." That is, Parashurama ended the Kali Yuga and began the Satya Yuga.

Comment: So Parashurama slaying the kings of earth 21 times all happened during the same Kali Yuga as Kartaveerya Arjuna or subsequent Kali Yugas? Also, who are the 'Mlecchas' of the previous Kali Yugas?

Comment: @Naveen I think it all happened in one Yuga; he was like the Kalki of that Yuga.  As far as Mlecchas go, just as there are non-Hindu religions in the present Kali Yuga, there must have been non-Hindu religions in the past as well.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Have you heard of the Adama and Havyavathy story from the Bhavishya Purana? They are said to be the progenitors of the Mlecchas. Is the Bhavishya Purana really authentic? Because it is the same purana that supposedly contains references to Jesus and Prophet Mohammad which seems like a fabrication.

Comment: @Naveen The Bhavishya Purana is certainly an authentic Mahapurana, it's just that it contains a lot of interpolations.  I think the Adama and Havyavathi stuff was inserted by someone to connect the Christian story of Adam and Eve to Hinduism.  You asked me about them in a previous thread.  They're not mentioned among the children of Kardama in other scriptures.

Comment: If Rama lived in 24th Treta Yuga then what happened in 25th, 26th, 27th, 28th Treta Yuga? No incarnation happened in those yugas or what,  because we are still reading history of that ancient yuga.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Generally, we have the most information about the events in the most recent Yugas, and about events that happened close to the creation of the world.  For the most part don't have much information about about what happened in between, except when something really major like the Ramayana happened.  There probably were some incarnations of Vishnu in the 25th, 26th, and 27th Mahayugas, we just don't know about them.  But the Shiva Purana discusses incarnations of Shiva that happened in those Mahayugas, and we know who the Vyasas of those Mahayugas were.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Or it just happened in the last Treta Yuga as the date 5114 BC, the footprints of Hanuman and the Ram Setu say.

Comment: @Chinmay Well, I don't think the footprints and the bridge provide much evidence for Yukteswar's theory, but in any case I don't know of any scriptures that say that the Ramayana happened in the most recent Treta Yuga.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I am only telling what my eyes are seeing, I don't think my eyes can see the footprints that happened millions of years ago, I don't think my eyes can see Ram Setu that was constructed in 24th Treta Yuga. Moreover, I don't take everything written in scriptures seriously. If Lord Shiva or Vishnu says me so then I will believe it. Also, I think many times in the past I have given you enough facts in favour of Sri Yukteswar's yuga theory.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria So you don't accept the authority of Sabda Pramana?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Also, you have given 1 proof for Yukteswar's theory. You said Parshurama was born in 19th Treta Yuga. According to Sri Yukteswar's Yuga theory, after ascending Treta Yuga comes ascending Satya Yuga. And that's what you said, "Rooting out all evils from the earth, he caused the primeval Yuga to set in."

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Yes, Parashurama was born in the 19th Treta Yuga, but I don't think there are any scriptures that mention that that's when he killed the Kshatriyas of the Earth.  He think he did that much later, in one of the Kali Yugas, presumably the 19th Kali Yuga.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Did Drona Parva specifically mention Kali Yuga? Absolutely Not.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria No, it didn't mention what Yuga Parashurama killed them in.  Let me see if other scriptures mention it.

Comment: You mention that Matsya avatar in Kali Yuga. But the reference you gave doesn't say that Satyavrata Muni saw the fish incarnation in the Kali Yuga?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one event that happened in a previous kaliyuga. From [Skanda Purana, Pursotama-kshetra-Mahatmy, Section 2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371628.html)

> 21-23. In a former **Kaliyuga**, O Brāhmaṇas, the Prajāpati (Patriarch) named Dakṣa was moved with pity on seeing men suffering from distresses coming from bodies and other sources. He went there and celebrated the great festival in the manner described by me. He was the first person to do so. On the third day in the bright half of the month of Vaiśākha he applied sandal-paste on the body of the Lord and joyously repeated this prayer:

This section talks about how to perform worship of Lord Pursottama on Akshaya Tritiya. Prajapati Daksha was the first person to do so, and he did it in a previous Kaliyuga

Comment: Good finding Carmen.