# Why couldn't the mighty kings of the past sustain their lineage and/or kingdom to the present?

Tags: history

We see in the scriptures that the kings like Rama and Krishna were all knowers and most powerful in the world. Why couldn't they sustain their kingdoms or lineage and the same social systems to this day? Why couldn't they see a deterioration in a relatively short span of a few centuries from what was the golden period?

Comment: Well, just because someone is a great king doesn't mean that all their descendants will be great kings. Eventually the quality of kings may deteriorate, especially as the Kali Yuga advances.  For instance, the illustrious Kuru dynasty was ended when Arjuna's descendant Kshemaka was killed by his advisor, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7749/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I agree this is true as we observe it today. However, my question is why those kings were unable to foresee or do anything about such situation that is inevitably going to arise in the future. Especially since they were the eternal masters of all the knowledge there is.

Comment: I think you cannot do anything in front of god's will. If god wants anything to happen it will happen, but you can change the will of god by bhakti!

Comment: i don't know about Rama but Krishna voluntarily made his lineage end. He prayed to Shiva( The Destroyer) to have son exactly like him so that Yadu clan could end. Samba was responsible for end of Yadu clan, See this wiki page for more info.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(Krishna%27s_son)

Comment: Everything in this world is subject to growth and decay. What grows must decay. Even God when He accepts birth in this world is subject to death.