# Authentic sources of history after the Mahabharat war

Tags: mahabharata

There is a lot of material on the Internet with vastly varying degree of authenticity and differences of opinions on this topic. Are there any authors, publications that are most reliable/scientific/trustworthy about history after the Mahabharat war up to the part of Indian history that is well researched/generally accepted in more recent centuries after that.

Chapters within Mahabharat describe some of the post war events, but I am looking for authentic research done on major history/chronology of events that connect the dots between end of Mahabharat war up until the point of already well known/researched/accepted eras of Indian history.

Comment: Are you looking for descriptions of events after the Mahabharata in Hindu scripture?

Comment: Anywhere. Be it in scriptures or in books or papers as long as the content is generally regarded as authentic and reliable (rather than still debated) in community of sensible authors, researchers and readers (rather than blind believers and unscientific proponents of their own theories).

Comment: Quora has the same topic going and as you can see there is much variation. https://www.quora.com/What-happened-after-Mahabharata My goal is to build a list of material about the post war history that one can rely on for accuracy and objectivity.

Comment: Well, obviously secular historians would dispute the validity of information found in Hindu scripture.  In any case, History.SE may be a better fit for your question if you're just trying to find historical documentation of Indian history, rather than specifically what Hindu scripture has to say on the subject.

Comment: By the way, you may be interested in this question: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7747/36

Comment: By History.SE if you mean http://history.stackexchange.com/ there is not really much in there. But I may post a question there too later on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to History.SE. OP wants authentic proof. Hinduism.SE is based on beliefs!!

Comment: Not accurate. I am just trying to build a list of reliable academic references for this part of history. Happy to move to history.se if that is what community thinks is appropriate.

Comment: @NaymeshMistry We can answer that only with scriptures like Mahabharata, so there is no scientifically accepted(what historian's expect) history here.

Comment: I am aware of that. Perhaps anything that is close enough to a reasonable/believable material in such a situation is all we can work with and that is fine.

Comment: @NaymeshMistry In that case, please edit the question to remove 'authentic' etc. and simply write "which scriptures discuss post Mahabharata war..." then people will answer what they know. You can then decide for yourself if that is authentic or not.

Comment: Net came during recent times.  But the epic is very old. You cannot compare thenet topics with the epic writers. The question is off topic.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some good academic sources I have found:

- [Political history of ancient India, from the accession of Parikshit to the extinction of the Gupta dynasty
  by Raychaudhuri, HemChanndra](https://archive.org/details/politicalhistory00raycuoft)
- [Ancient India, 2000 B.C.-800 A.D. by Dutt, Romesh Chunder, 1848-1909](https://archive.org/details/ancientindia00dutt)