# Who were the kings (other than Kartavirya Arjuna) killed by Lord Parashurama?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, parashurama, chandravansh, suryavansh

Arjuna (son of Kritavirya hence, famously known as Kartavirya Arjuna) was king of Maheshmati. He was from Yadavas or Haihayas (a branch of Yadavas). He is believed to be an incarnation of Sudarshana Chakra. He got boon from Lord Dattatreya which made him so powerful. His greatest deeds were his defeat and imprisonment of Ravana, king of Lanka. Kartavirya Arjuna eventually met his death at the hands of Lord Parashurama.

The above story is found in most of scriptures but there are many other sources which claim that Lord Parshurama killed all the Kshatriya that too 21 time as described [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/why-did-lord-parshurama-kill-the-kshatriya-kings). Mahabharata (in [Adi Parva -> Adivansavatarana Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01065.htm)) even mention that

> The son of Jamadagni (Parasurama), after twenty-one times making the earth bereft of Kshatriyas wended to that best of mountains Mahendra and there began his ascetic penances. And at that time when the earth was bereft of Kshatriyas, the Kshatriya ladies, desirous of offspring, used to come, O monarch, to the Brahmanas and Brahmanas of rigid vows had connection with them during the womanly season alone, but never, O king, lustfully and out of season.

[image]

But I didn't come across any story which says that so and so famous king was killed by Lord Parshurama. So, my questions are

- Name of kings from Ikshvaku vansh who were killed by Lord Parashurama?
- Name of kings from Pauravas who were killed by Lord Parashurama?
- Name of kings from Yadavas (other than Kartavirya Arjuna) who were killed by Lord Parashurama?
- Name of kings from any other famous dynasties who were killed by Lord Parashurama?

In short,

**Did Lord Parashurama kill any king who was not from Yadavas or Haihayas?** If yes, then **who were they?** If no, then **what's the riddle of killing all the Kshatriyas 21 times?**

Comment: Answer to this question here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/419/what-did-kashyapa-do-with-the-earth-after-he-received-it-from-parashurama tells us about various kshatriya children saved by various means during Parashurama purge. So presumably all their fathers who have been named were killed. Viduratha, saudasa, sivi etc.

Comment: Mahabharata is mentioning certain king called "Dantakrur" , whom Parashurama killed. But there is no info. about whether he was Kshatriya king or belonging to which lineage.

Comment: Also MB is giving the names of regions "Kashmir ,Dadar , Kunti ,Shudrak, Malav ,Anga ,Vang ,Kalinga, Videha ,Tamralipta ,Rakshovaaha" etc. Parashurama killed many Kings from these and many more regions.