# Why did Parshuram genocide Kshatriyas?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas

Parshuram's father Jamadagni was killed by Kativeer Arjun , Why did he kill all Kshatriyas and that too 21 times ?

Comment: The thing I want to know did he pay for what he did I mean law of karma

Comment: https://medium.com/@hrising19/why-did-parashuram-kill-the-kshatriyas-from-the-earth-for-21-times-2e6a6d048db4

Comment: @AbhinavRaj Unless he killed Kshatriya children and women , I don't think he committed an sin. Killing men (especially Kshatriya men) in a war combat after giving them a proper a calling for a fight is not sin. It was the dharma of that age. 
And I don't think he killed children or women as otherwise he wouldn't have been able to eliminate Kshatriya 21 times

Comment: @AbhinavRaj Also men who get killed in war get heaven. And I think since Parshuram was avatar of Vishnu, they might have been got Moksha as people getting killed from the hand of God get Moksha.

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered on the site before: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/why-did-lord-parshurama-kill-the-kshatriya-kings